# Помогите понять,написать алгоритм программы

Tags: java

Всем добрый день, начал только изучать Java, нашел сайт на котором постепенно пишешь свой первый проект, но столкнулся с проблемой на 3 этапе из 6.

Условие программы:Если в кофемашине достаточно расходных материалов для приготовления указанного количества кофе, программа должна напечатать «Да, я могу приготовить такое количество кофе». Если кофемашина может приготовить больше, программа должна вывести «Да, я могу приготовить такое количество кофе (и даже N больше)», где N - количество дополнительных чашек кофе, которые может приготовить кофемашина. . Если ресурсов недостаточно для приготовления указанного количества кофе, программа должна вывести «Нет, я могу приготовить только N чашек кофе».
Как и на предыдущем этапе, кофемашине требуется 200 мл воды, 50 мл молока и 15 г кофейных зерен для приготовления одной чашки кофе.

```
package machine;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class CoffeeMachine {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
                            /*Scanner*/
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Write how many ml of water the coffee machine has:");
        var water = s.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Write how many ml of milk the coffee machine has:");
        var milk = s.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Write how many grams of coffee beans the coffee machine has:");
        var coffeeBeans = s.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Write how many cups of coffee you will need: ");
        var valueOfCups = s.nextInt();
                            //for 1 cup
        var oneCupWater=200;
        var oneCupMilk=50;
        var oneCupCoffeeBeans=15;
                            /*Possible for All*/
        var possibleWater = water/oneCupWater;
        var possibleMilk = milk/oneCupMilk;
        var possibleCoffeeBeans= coffeeBeans/oneCupCoffeeBeans;
                            /*Minimum*/
        var min = Math.min(Math.min(possibleWater,possibleMilk),possibleCoffeeBeans);
                            /*Instruction IF ELSE-IF IF*/
        if (min<valueOfCups)System.out.println("Yes, I can make that amount of coffee (and even "+(min-valueOfCups)+" more than that)");
        else if(min==valueOfCups)System.out.println("Yes, I can make that amount of coffee");
        else System.out.println("No, I can make only "+(min) +" cups of coffee");

    }
}
```

Вот что смог написать, подскажите что не так в алгоритме с if, просто на словах, код не нужен,хочу сам до него дойти.

```
Wrong answer in test #2

Your output:
No, I can make only 2 cups of coffee
Right output:
Yes, I can make that amount of coffee (and even 2 more than that)

Please find below the output of your program during this failed test.
Note that the '>' character indicates the beginning of the input line.

---

Write how many ml of water the coffee machine has:
> 600
Write how many ml of milk the coffee machine has:
> 153
Write how many grams of coffee beans the coffee machine has:
> 100
Write how many cups of coffee you will need: 
> 1
No, I can make only 2 cups of coffee
```

Comment: если вам нужно подсказать, что тут неправильно, то неправильный знак в условном операторе. измените if (min<valueOfCups) на if (min>valueOfCups) и все будет работать. но это по прежнему треш. как минимум заканчивайте писать var, их не для того добавили, чтобы сделать javascript из java. попытайтесь разбить класс хотя бы на методы, это очень улучшит читаемость вашего кода, да и в целом кодстанет более гибким. константы выносите из методов в переменные класса/отдельный класс/ресурсы. любое внешнее воздействие - зло, включая ввод пользователя. учитывайте потенциальные ошибки при вводе.

Comment: спасибо большое за совет, только начинаю учиться, в скором времени как раз хотел начать читать книгу,как сделать свой код получше. ООП пока что не начинал учить, занимаюсь по книге Шилдта + на одном сайте, ооп у них в разделах в будущем.

Comment: не за что, правда советы никак не касались ооп))

Comment: Тогда увы пока что я совсем дерево,понял только то что var не стоит писать, а про остальные моменты не могу понять, увы) В будущем,надеюсь вернусь сюда и смогу "догнать" до всего)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все просто поменяйте знак `if (min > valueOfCups)`. Вы говорите что у вас `min` чашек кофе получится. И если min больше чем чашек нужно, т.е `valueOfCups` тогда ....

```
package machine;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class CoffeeMachine {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
                            /*Scanner*/
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Write how many ml of water the coffee machine has:");
        var water = s.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Write how many ml of milk the coffee machine has:");
        var milk = s.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Write how many grams of coffee beans the coffee machine has:");
        var coffeeBeans = s.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Write how many cups of coffee you will need: ");
        var valueOfCups = s.nextInt();
                            //for 1 cup
        var oneCupWater=200;
        var oneCupMilk=50;
        var oneCupCoffeeBeans=15;
                            /*Possible for All*/
        var possibleWater = water/oneCupWater;
        var possibleMilk = milk/oneCupMilk;
        var possibleCoffeeBeans= coffeeBeans/oneCupCoffeeBeans;
                            /*Minimum*/
        var min = Math.min(Math.min(possibleWater,possibleMilk),possibleCoffeeBeans);
                            /*Instruction IF ELSE-IF IF*/
        if (min>valueOfCups)System.out.println("Yes, I can make that amount of coffee (and even "+(min-valueOfCups)+" more than that)");
        else if(min==valueOfCups)System.out.println("Yes, I can make that amount of coffee");
        else System.out.println("No, I can make only "+(min) +" cups of coffee");

    }
}
```